# Stack bar chart is not updating highchart angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, highcharts

I want to update stack bar chart completely but right now chart is not updating completely it's just adding new data into existing chart. Here is the demo

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-smoke-irbjj?file=/src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: You mean update the number of each fruit of each user?

Comment: @AlbertoValerio, As you seen in the demo, I want to update the value of each fruit of each user that is once is click on update on apple values wanted to show on the graph for all user

Comment: @SebastianWędzel, can you help me in this, please

Answer (score 0):

You are only updating the apples. Add the others fruits in this format.

```
update() {
    this.drawChart(
      [
        {
          name: "apple",
          data: [34, 56, 76, 99],
          color: "#236bb4",
          type: "bar"
        },
        {
          name: "banana",
          data: [34, 56, 76, 99],
          color: "#ff6bc6",
          type: "bar"
        },
        {
          name: "mango",
          data: [34, 56, 76, 99],
          color: "#006bf1",
          type: "bar"
        }
      ],
      ["Mueed", "Ali", "Ahmed", "Amir"]
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No this is not what I want

Comment: Explain me further, please, I'm not undestanding your question @MueedUllah

Answer (score 0):

Updating the chart while using highcharts-angular wrappers should be performed by changing the `chartOptions`.
In the demo below, you might find the recommended way of updating the chart.
When for some reason it is crucial for you to destroy and then render once again use the `destroy` method first, creating a reference to that chart. 
But in my opinion, when you want to put another data into the chart(update), there is no need to use that.

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#destroy
**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-ocbghf

Comment: In my scenario there are some input filters on the page when I choose 'apple' so only apple data I received through API, so after apply the filter I want to show only apple bar on the chart but right now apples value are added to current data which is I won't needed

Comment: When you add a reference to the chart you might use the `remove` series method and then in place of that series add another one.
Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-tbmiwg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#remove
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#addSeries